# How do I access to a method of a class of a class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to access a method `sayName()` contained in a class `Klass` inside another class `Manny`.

```
class Manny {
    class Klass {
        func sayName() {
            print("Klass")
        }
    }
}
```

Writing `Manny.Klass.sayName()` returns an error because it expects some code inside the parentheses:

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Though, the method `sayName()` doesn't have any parameters.

I know I can send messages to a class `Manny` with the dot-notation `Manny.myMethod()`, but how do I access to a method of a class inside another class?

Comment: create an instance or make it static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your function `sayName()` is an instance function, not a class function. Therefore without an instance of the class `Klasse` you cannot call the method.

Either change the type of the function to be of class type or create an instance first and call the function on that instance:

```
class Manny {
    class Klass {
        class func sayName() {
            print("Klass")
        }
    }
}

Manny.Klass.sayName()
```

**OR**

```
class Manny {
    class Klass {
        func sayName() {
            print("Klass")
        }
    }
}

let klasse = Manny.Klass()
klasse.sayName()
```

Both correctly print

> Klass

Answer (score 1):

As you're calling the method on the class you have to declare the method as class method by adding the keyword `class`

```
class Manny {
  class Klass {
    class func sayName() {
      print("Klass")
    }
  }
}
```